# How can my users be able to record audio as long as they want and also be able to pause it using sounddevice in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sounddevice

I am using **sounddevice**, **scipy** and **playsound** in my project. I have a file named **record.py** whose source is given below :

```
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from playsound import playsound

fs = 44100  # this is the frequency sampling; also: 4999, 64000
seconds = 5  # Duration of recording

myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
print("Starting: Speak now!")
sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
print("finished")
write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file
playsound("output.wav")
```

The above given code works fine, but I have a problem. You may have noticed the **seconds** variable in the source, whose value is set to *5*. Therefore, after *5sec* the recording stops automatically and saves itself as **output.wav** and then gets played. Is there any way such that I didn't require to define the duration, that means the user can record the audio as long as she/he wants. Also by pressing the **Shift** key she/he can pause as well as resume the recording, and finally stop it by pressing **Enter**, after which the file automatically saves and gets played. So can this be done ?

Comment: Sure, this can be done. As a starting point, you can have a look at the [rec_unlimited.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_unlimited.py) example.